# Distributing XCFrameworks as binary targets with chain dependencies

Tags: ios, libraries, swift-package-manager, xcframework

New to distributing XCFrameworks via SPM.

The issue I'm having is that I have 5 frameworks, each having a dependency OF ALL THE PREVIOUS frameworks:

A
B, depends on A
C, depends on both B & A
D, depends on C, B & A &
E depending of all the ones above

The issue with my Package.swift, is that I need to add EACH package to the main app for them to be added to Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content

What would the "E" Framework look like so just adding this package ALSO adds all of its dependencies to the main app?

Sorry if vague, I'm just a bit lost

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately as of now SPM doesn't support declaring dependency for binary targets, what you can do as a workaround is to declare a dummy wrapper target and add multiple binary targets as dependency. You have to add dummy source file for the wrapper target as well. For an example you can look into [package manifest](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Package.swift) for [firebase-ios-sdk](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk), especially the `FirebaseAnalyticsWrapper` target